# How can I tell if a question has been shared?

Tags: support, questions, edits, sharing

If you look at the edit history of a question (ie [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/posts/21216/revisions)), you can see if that question has been shared. However, if the question has not been edited then I don't see a way of finding out if it has been shared.

Is there an alternative way of seeing if a question has been shared?

Comment: try this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3616/147247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "shared" I assume you mean tweeted by the SE bot, which leaves an entry in the post history.  For other kinds of sharing, like when somebody uses the "share" link and posts to his blog or wherever, there's no way to know.  (If it's popular enough you might see Announcer badges pop up.)

You can see the revision history of any post by manually constructing a URL of the following form: (bae-url)/posts/###/revisions.  For example, the revisions for your question can be found at https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/246097/revisions.

Comment: Ah, didnt realize that it only posts that for StackBot stuff.